# Puppet ignore part of templated file

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to ignore part of a templated file?

I have a service which has a config file and each time the service starts it writes the start time in the config file. This makes puppet detect a change and since I have it notifying the service it will restart the service. I don't want puppet to restart the service shortly after I have just started it.

So is there a way for to make puppet ignore part of a templated file?

Comment: Does the service support any include directive in the config file?  Can you have puppet write to a file that gets included by the main configuration file that gets changed locally?

Comment: Interesting workaround suggestion. It's an XML based config file so in theory I might be able to use and `!ENTITY` reference. I'm not sure if this will break it though.

Comment: Another uglier option might be to have puppet drop the new config file some temporary location, and write your own script that does a replace/restart that gets called by an `exec`.  Your own script would have to handle the file comparison itself, and know how to ignore the irrelevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, puppet calculates an md5 of the file to check for file changes. Is it possible to write the start time to another file?

Comment: Right, that's the pickle. I'm thinking my only option is to read that part of the file as a fact and use it in the template `<%=@start_time=>`. lol

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similiar to Zoredache's, but varies slightly in that you don't need an intelligent script to do the comparison.

Let's say your configuration file is `/etc/my_application.conf` and it looks like this:

```
start_time=<some value set by application on start-up>
option1=VALUE
...
```

In puppet, add a file to files/ for your configuration file, that looks like:

```
start_time=DummyValue
option1=VALUE
...
```

Then, use a manifest that deployes the file to an alternate location, and if changes exist, triggers a copy that then triggers the service, like so:

```
file { '/etc/my_application.staging.conf':
  ensure => present,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/my_application/my_application.conf',
  owner  => ...
  notify => Exec['install-my_application.conf'],
}

exec { 'install-my_application.conf':
  refreshonly => true,
  command     => '/bin/cp /etc/my_application.staging.conf /etc/my_application.conf',
  notify      => Service['my_application'],
}

service { 'my_application':
  ...
}
```

This allows you to restart on new configuration changes, but **will not** restart the service if my_application.conf is modified locally.  This isn't a *perfect* solution because it does not save you from local modifications, but hopefully you can manage those with permissions and a clear warning at the top of the configuration file.